# error using subprocess when calling from another script in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to use subprocess to call another script, but being a beginner I'm not quite getting there.

The first script defines the variables, and it will be saved in differing locations so it can't have an absolute path.

The second script calls in the variables from the first script and will use them to do its thing. This script will stay in the same directory.

This is what I have so far

script1.py:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

x = 'VALUE'

import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "/mnt/scratch/script2.py"])
```

script2.py:

```
import sys
import subprocess

from script1 import x
```

Seems pretty basic but the error coming up is: ImportError: No module named x

Cheers

Comment: Why do you need to call script2 from script1? If script1 is only for defining of the variables, you can run the script2 stright away because it imports the script1. As it is now I think you have a cycling dependencies (call -> import -> call -> import -> ...)

Comment: yep you're right, I took out the call in the first script and ran execfile instead and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your script 1.py is in some folder suppose D:\Users\Desktop\Test
While your Script2.py  is in some other folder

provide path to the folder location of file 1 in script2.py with sys.path and that should work

```
import sys
import subprocess
sys.path.append('D:\Users\Desktop\Test')
from script1 import x
print x
```